# C# groupBox lotto, need help assigning variable for group box

Tags: c#, variables, groupbox

```
        private void LineUpNumbers ()
        {
        Array.Sort(lineArray[currentSelectedLine]);    // Sorts the array in ascending order.
        string numberBox = "Line" + (currentSelectedLine + 1).ToString() + "NumberBox";
        string nb;

        Image[] CircleColours = new Image[6] {Properties.Resources.BlueCircle, Properties.Resources.RedCircle , Properties.Resources.OrangeCircle , Properties.Resources.PurpleCircle , Properties.Resources.GreenCircle , Properties.Resources.YellowCircle};
        Random r = new Random();
        CircleColours = CircleColours.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToArray();


        for (int i = 0; i <6; i++)    // Populates NumberBoxes with the numbers from the array
        {
            nb = numberBox + (i + 1);
            Line1.Controls[nb].Text = lineArray[currentSelectedLine][i].ToString();
            Line1.Controls[nb].BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
        }

    }
```

Hi, 
In the above snippet I'd like to change Line1 to be a string variable, but I'm not sure on the correct syntax for doing so. Could anyone help with a solution for this?  This is C#

Line1 is the GrouBox name.
I'd like to be able to change Line1 to a string. Like this:

```
string groupBoxName = "Line1";
groupBoxName.buttonName.BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```

The code doesn't work though

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Controls` array of the Form `this.Controls` like this...

```
string groupBoxName = "Line1";
Control groupBox = this.Controls[groupBoxName];
groupBox.Controls[nb].BackgroundImage = CircleColours[i];
```

...just like the way you are getting the `NumberBox` dynamically from the `Controls` array of the `GroupBox`.